# Way to lock UIAccessibility focus

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiaccessibility

Is there any way to lock the focus when in a VoiceOver mode? I know that I can move focus to a specific element using `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` , but the user can still navigate to the rest of the screen.

Example: I am showing a spinner when a request is being made. While the spinner does gain focus, is there any way to lock the focus on the spinner until it is dismissed? Right now, the user can move on to other elements in the view.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622584-canbecomefocused

Comment: @Sulthan The property you linked will just determine whether an element can get focussed. I want to know if I can lock the focus on an in-focus element for as long as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the easiest way to do this is to use `accessibilityViewIsModal`. I had a spinner that I wanted to keep in focus.

> self.spinner.accessibilityViewIsModal = YES;

Also, I faced another issue where thought the user wasnt able to navigate within the view itself, the focus did move to the custom nav ar ion a swipe. I fixed that using

> self.navigationController.navigationBar.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;